# RavenDb Index sorting

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

Let's imagine we have the simplest Map index:

```
Map = posts => from post in posts
               orderby post.DateTime
               select new { Id = post.Id, DateTime = post.DateTime }
```

How does OrderBy clause will influence on Map index results? Does it define a default documents ordering in the case if your query doesn't provide order clause explicitly? How are documents sorted in the case no ordering clause was provided neither in index nor in query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This orderby will be ignored at all - it has no effect on how the index will be executed.
By default (if you don't specify a specific ordering) you will have lexicographic order.

You can either sepecify an order on the index itself (see here: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/customizing-results-order) or at query time.

Comment: I guess the link you provided tells not about order on the index itself - it tells how to sort fields if query is sorted by them explicitly.

Comment: No - it tells about different sort options. These are the ones that determine the order of the documents inside the index.